# how to restore last saved code in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, revert

In Eclipse, I accidentally SVN update my code to HEAD version of the repository. My local code is what I want to keep, so how do I revert to that? 
Tks.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to do this:

1. Right click on the file you would like to restore
2. Go to Team
3. Select Show Local History
4. Choose the desired date
5. Copy the content and paste in your actual file

And it's done... Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the local history in eclipse. Refer to this link

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fteam_synchronize_localhistory_example.htm

Comment: @Shraddha: Tks for replying, The thing is when I tried "Restore from local history", it said "No additional members found in local history" as seen in the screenshot here https://plus.google.com/photos/107856326230892017714/albums/5692691657031580193?authkey=CJef_qCevc-S-gE 
I've checked my Eclipse workspace preference, the setting is still keeping files in 7 days.
Any other ideas?