# Logic error towards the end

Tags: java, arrays

I'm finishing up a project that I have due this week.  It is a program that gets the intersection and difference of the arrays in ascending order.  Everything is working as far as the methods go, but I was trying to get fancy and add a line break in between user responses, but I must have erased something somewhere and cant' find my log to that part.  Its suppose to just repeat what is in the do while loop, but when I go again for the second time, it looks like it is multiplying the sets of numbers I'm suppos to put int.  I know it has to be a simple logic error but my head is fried at this point.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class settest {

    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * This method will retrieve "size" number of unique
     * integers from keyboard and placed into an array set. 
     */
    public static void getData(int [] set, int size){

        boolean isUnique=false;
        int input; int count=0;

        while(count < size){
            input = kbd.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++) 
            {
                if (input == set[i]) 
                {
                    isUnique = true;
                }   
            }

            if (!isUnique) 
            {
                set[count] = input;
                count++;
            }
            isUnique = false;
        }

    }

    /*
     * This method will calculate the intersection of two sets of arrays.
     * It needs to receive two sets of arrays, their size, and a holding
     * array as parameters from the main program.
     * When finished the method will return the numbers that are in common
     * in both sets (resultSize) 
     */
    public static int intersection(int [] setA, int sizeA , int [] setB, 
            int sizeB, int [] resultSet){

        int resultSize=0;
        for(int x=0; x<sizeA; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<sizeB; y++)
            {
                if(setA[x]==setB[y])
                {
                    resultSet[resultSize]=setA[x];
                    resultSize++;
                }
            }
        }

        return resultSize;
    }

    /*
     * Calculates the difference (A-B) of the two array sets. 
     * It will received the set [], size of correct array and in 
     * ascending order as parameters.
     * Returns the correct array size for the received resultSet[]
     */
    public static int difference(int [] setA, int sizeA , int [] setB, 
            int sizeB, int [] resultSet){

        int resultSize=0; boolean sameVal=false;

        for(int x=0; x<sizeA; x++ ){
            for(int y=0; y<sizeB; y++){
                if(setA[x]==setB[y]){
                    sameVal=true;
                }
            }
            if(!sameVal){
                resultSet[resultSize]=setA[x];
                resultSize++;
            }
            sameVal=false;
        }
        return resultSize;
    }

    /*
     * Method will sort the numbers in set[] array into ascending order. 
     */
    public static void sort(int [] set, int size){

        for(int x=0; x< size-1; x++)
        {
            for(int y=x+1; y<size; y++)
            {   
                if(set[x] > set[y])
                {
                    int temp = set[x];
                    set[x] = set[y];
                    set[y] = temp;
                }
            }     
        }
    }

    public static final int MAXSIZE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] setA = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int [] setB = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int [] resultSet = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int sizeA=0, sizeB=0;int resultSize=0;
        String repeat;

        do{
            System.out.println("ENTER 2 SETS OF NUMBERS.\n");
            System.out.println("HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR FIRST SET?");
            sizeA=kbd.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<sizeA; i++){

                if (sizeA>MAXSIZE){
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED."
                            + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT. \n");
                    sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("\nENTER THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS");

            getData(setA, sizeA);
            sort(setA,sizeA);


            System.out.println("\nHOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR SECOND SET?");
            sizeB=kbd.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<sizeB; i++){

                if (sizeB>MAXSIZE){
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED.  \n"
                            + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT.\n ");
                    sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("\nENTER THE SECOND SET OF NUMBERS");

            getData(setB, sizeB);
            sort(setB, sizeB);

            System.out.println("\nINTERSECTION:");
            resultSize=intersection(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB, resultSet);
            for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
                System.out.print(resultSet[i] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n\nDIFFERENCE OF A-B:");
            resultSize=difference(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB, resultSet);
            for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
                System.out.print(resultSet[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nDIFFERENCE OF B-A:");
            resultSize=difference(setB,sizeB,setA,sizeA, resultSet);
            for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
                System.out.print(resultSet[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n\nDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?");

            repeat= kbd.next().toLowerCase();

        } while(repeat.equals("y"));

    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
ENTER 2 SETS OF NUMBERS.
```

HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR FIRST SET?
3

ENTER THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS
4
3
2

HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR SECOND SET?
2

ENTER THE SECOND SET OF NUMBERS
5
6

INTERSECTION:

DIFFERENCE OF A-B:
2 3 4

DIFFERENCE OF B-A:
5 6

DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?
Y
ENTER 2 SETS OF NUMBERS.

HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR FIRST SET?
1

ENTER THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS
6

HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR SECOND SET?
6

ENTER THE SECOND SET OF NUMBERS
3
5
4
1
0
9
7

INTERSECTION:

DIFFERENCE OF A-B:
6

DIFFERENCE OF B-A:
1 3 4 5 7 9

DO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?
8
GOODBYE

On the second go around in the loop the user numbers increment somehow to where it ads 1 or a couple

Comment: which ide did you use if it netbeans you can revert your code back

Comment: please have a look at it `http://stackoverflow.com/a/12579781/1262764`

Comment: its not working.  i don't have those options.

Comment: please post sample inputs and desired output for your application in order to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the following code will help you. You can move the initialization array part into the while loop so that you can initialize the size of the array with user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sizeA=0, sizeB=0;int resultSize=0;
    String repeat;

    do{        
        System.out.println("ENTER 2 SETS OF NUMBERS.\n");
        System.out.println("HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR FIRST SET?");
        sizeA=kbd.nextInt();

        int [] setA = new int[sizeA ]; //Initializing Array of size that user inputs.

        for(int i=0; i<sizeA; i++){

            if (sizeA>MAXSIZE){
                System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED."
                        + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT. \n");
                sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("\nENTER THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS");

        getData(setA, sizeA);
        sort(setA,sizeA);


        System.out.println("\nHOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR SECOND SET?");
        sizeB=kbd.nextInt();

        int [] setB = new int[sizeB]; //Initializing Array of size that user inputs.

        for(int i=0; i<sizeB; i++){

            if (sizeB>MAXSIZE){
                System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED.  \n"
                        + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT.\n ");
                sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("\nENTER THE SECOND SET OF NUMBERS");

        getData(setB, sizeB);
        sort(setB, sizeB);

        /* Initializing the result array with Largest among sizeA and sizeB*/
        resultSize = sizeA;
        if(sizeB > sizeA)
        {
             resultSize = sizeB;
        }
        int [] resultSet = new int[resultSize];

        System.out.println("\nINTERSECTION:");
        resultSize=intersection(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB, resultSet);
        for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
            System.out.print(resultSet[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nDIFFERENCE OF A-B:");
        resultSize=difference(setA,sizeA,setB,sizeB, resultSet);
        for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
            System.out.print(resultSet[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nDIFFERENCE OF B-A:");
        resultSize=difference(setB,sizeB,setA,sizeA, resultSet);
        for(int i=0; i<resultSize; i++){
            System.out.print(resultSet[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?");

        repeat= kbd.next().toLowerCase();

    } while(repeat.equals("y"));
```

Comment: Wow. You guys solved my two issues:  Find what I accidentally erased (the arrays inside loop) and my logic error that was a result of initializing the arrays outside of the while loop while having them again inside of it.  Doing this is illogical because as @David Jones said the original array never really discards all of its numbers and only adds them to the 2nd iteration array.  Meaning that in my original edit, each set was not discarding the original one and just making the array size bigger each iteration. Thanks David and Shridhar.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without a preview of your output, but I'll take a stab. It looks like to me, during the second iteration of the do/while, if you use array sizes that are smaller than the original arrays then you could keep garbage from the first iteration.

It's better practice to re-initialize these variable during each iteration.

```
do {

            System.out.println("ENTER 2 SETS OF NUMBERS.\n");
            System.out.println("HOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR FIRST SET?");
            sizeA=kbd.nextInt();
            while(sizeA>MAXSIZE){
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED."
                            + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT. \n");
                    sizeA = kbd.nextInt();

            }
            System.out.println("\nENTER THE FIRST SET OF NUMBERS");
            setA = new int[MAXSIZE];

            getData(setA, sizeA);
            sort(setA,sizeA);


            System.out.println("\nHOW MANY NUMBERS IN YOUR SECOND SET?");
            sizeB=kbd.nextInt();
            while(sizeB>MAXSIZE){
                    System.out.println("\nERROR: SET SIZE LIMIT EXCEEDED.  \n"
                            + "ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT.\n ");
                    sizeB = kbd.nextInt();

            }
            System.out.println("\nENTER THE SECOND SET OF NUMBERS");

            setB = new int[MAXSIZE];
            getData(setB, sizeB);
            sort(setB, sizeB);

            System.out.println("\nINTERSECTION:");


.
.
.
.


} while (repeat.equal('y'))
```

Does this solve your problem? Like I said earlier, I don't completely understand your problem, so if this doesn't solve it please provide some more detail so I can help.

Comment: Also, a quick question, I see that it looks a little cleaner doing it with the while loop, but for some reason Ive felt more confortable with for and do while loops as I am new to this whoe csci stuff, is there a difference in efficiency betwen the two techiniques?  As I said, im fairly new, so forgive my amateur questions.  I think this field is real neat and want to get better at it.  I just need to get better at understanding and breaking down the logic.

Comment: In your code you want to continue asking the user to enter a list size, until that value is correct. Using a for loop will not insure that this is true. Imagine that 'sizeA' or 'sizeB' are 10, this means that the for loop with run 10 times. If the users enters 11 incorrect values, this is result in an invalid size for sizeA. Also, the for loop depends on the size of 'sizeA' or 'sizeB'. You should almost never change the value of this size within the for loop. This could lead to some unwanted behavior. You should read more into Java basics, and probably do some basic java tutorials.